# Pointer flickering in 2019 VB browser app

Tags: vb.net

I’ve written a very simple VB browser app that points to http://W4UOA.dyndns.org:7010 to display a live stream. The curser flickers rapidly when over the browser window. I’ve double buffeted no help. Ideas?

Comment: Did you tried to set Internet Feature Controls in registry? You can set there which version of IE to be used for your application

Comment: I think that double buffering when not running in full-screen only serves to decrease the time where the mouse would be hidden. Usually the buffer switch or blit would be synchronised with the frame refresh, but I don't think that the web browser can do that. I think that the only way to have a stable mouse in a browser app is to let teh system use a hardware mouse pointer. Unless your graphics hardware is very old, you should have a hardware mouse pointer unless you have tried to use a full-colour mouse pointer via CSS. My advise would be to use a plain system mouse pointer.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll check this out.